# Prefast Warning:"Arithmetic Overflow: 32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value."

Tags: c, prefast

I have declared macros like this:

```
#define F_MASK_4_BIT 0xF
#define GET_F_4BIT_MASK(F, P) (((F) & (F_MASK_4_BIT << (P * 4))) >> (4 * P))
```

using macro like this:

```
uint8_t Feature = GET_F_4BIT_MASK(E, P);
```

Where **E** is **uint64_t** datatype
          **P** is **uint8_t**  datatype

Which gives warning by Prefast: **C6297: Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.**

How to fix this?

Comment: What is `FEATURE_MASK_4_BIT`. What is your platform/compiler etc. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: A static code analyzer can only tell you that this code *might* misbehave, it cannot guarantee that it actually does.  Right-shifting a signed value is unspecified, consider at least 0xFU to ensure the shift has defined behavior.  A bit less insulting than 0xFULL.  The days that macaroni like this was still useful are long gone btw, do favor a function and leave it up to the optimizer to inline it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty self-explaining. If `P` has any value larger than `7` (7*4=28, max is 31), the `F_MASK_4_BIT << (P * 4)` will overflow. Because `F_MASK_4_BIT` is a integer constant of type `int`.

Fix this by using an appropriate type for the integer constant:

```
#define F_MASK_4_BIT 0xFull
```

Comment: (Mandatory boring jokes about the mask being Full will follow...)

Comment: I thought about writing similar answer but I had doubts. Won't it cause the same message if `F` is replaced by a 32 bit value?

Comment: @Gerhardh What do you mean? `ull` = 64 bit.

Comment: Yes. The OP does `64bit & 32bit`. Your suggested fix changes this to `64bit & 64bit.` If the macro is used with a first parameter that only is 32 bits long, the replaced expression becomes `32bit & 64bit` as the right side is still `ull` and the shifted bits could end up in the higher 32 bits. But I don't know how clever that tool is.

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't understand what you are talking about. The shift has nothing to do with the left operand of &.